# Is it possible that shortest path between two vertices changes scale all the edge-weights?

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible that shortest path between two vertices changes if we add ten to all the weights of all edges in the graph? How about if we multiply all the edges-weight by ten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you add $10$ to the weights of all the edges. No if you multiply all edge-weights by $10$.

Take the graph with vertices $a$, $b$, and $c$ with weighted edges $(a \to b, 1)$, $(b \to c,1)$, and $(a \to c, 3)$. The $a \to b \to c$ path is the shortest path from  $a$ to $c$ now, but if you add $10$ to each weight, the direct path $a \to c$ will be shorter.

In the case of multiplication, if $N$ is the sum of the weights along the shortest path and $M$ is the sum of the weights of some competing path (so $N< M$), if you multiply all the edge-weights by $10$, that $10$ will factor out of the sum and you will still have $10N < 10M$.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication all weights by $10$ also changes weights of all pathes $10$ times, so the shortest one remains to be the shortest.

Addition is something else. Let $G \cong K_3$, $V(G) = \{\,1, 2, 3\,\}$ and $w(\{\,1, 2\,\}) = 1$, $w(\{\,1, 3\,\}) = 1$, $w(\{\,2, 3\,\}) = 3$. Then shortest $(1, 3)$-path is $1, 2, 3$, but after adding $10$ to all weights $1, 3$ becomes the shortest path.